# Java EE – chat app based on REST and JMS - handling channels

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I was given the task to write a chat application based on REST and JMS in Java EE.

There will be different channels in the chat. I wonder how to listen to messages only from a specific channel on the client-side.

Channels can be created by users while the application is running.

I was thinking about each channel being a separate Topic and I don't know if this is a good approach?

Is it possible to create Topics dynamically?

If there was only one main channel that all users are listening to, it would not be a problem, because each user would listen to the same Topic

Maybe there is a better solution than Topics?

Comment: You've got too many questions here. Please narrow it down to just one.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  The main question is, how to listen for specific chat channels with JMS?

Comment: You need to modify your actual question to make this clear. That said, asking "how to listen for specific chat channels with JMS?" is quite vague. Stack Overflow is for clear, concise programming questions. It's not meant for tutorials on how to create chat applications.